# How to find creation and annihilation operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, operators

I get confused when trying to find this. Please describe it as simply as possible, but keep in mind I have no budget whatsoever to pay for textbooks, so here goes:

How do you find the creation and annihilation operators of a scalar field given the Lagrangian density?

Comment: Would [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108375/) be of any help?

Comment: It is a little too hard to understand..